# Selecting elements for jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to target the following: `#Artwork > path:nth-child(10)`
How can I select this in jQuery since the following does not work:

```
(function($) {

var clouds = $('#Artwork > path:nth-child(10)')
TweenLite.to(clouds, 1, {opacity:0, y:50});

})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M2219,1043.65,1605.18,936.23c-143.54-25.13-502.39-25.13-645.93,0L449,1025.53V1231H2219Z" transform="translate(405)" style="fill: #030f33"/>
```

Comment: Please, add the html code too.

Comment: I have added the HTML part

Comment: @Dan The whole html code. Not just the one you want to select.

Comment: You just added the HTML relative to the `path` element BUT not the relevant part regarding the selector you are trying to use...

Comment: Are there any trusted websites to upload the code to? It is very long since it's exported SVG code maybe this will do: https://pastebin.com/qtKihJc6

Comment: use this website in the editor select the file icon with the code on it

Comment: I can not upload it with the editor as it is over 30000 characters

Answer (score -1):

Try $("#Artwork").find("path:nth-child(10)")

Comment: because they think its youtube if you dislike you down vote